# delete key from object and updating stateless components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
 const [description, setDescription] = React.useState({
   "key1":"first value",
   "key2":"second value",
   "key3":"third value"
 }
)
```

I have an object like the one provided above. i tried deleting a key from the object with the function below.

```
const remove = (key) => {
   delete description[key]
}
```

the problem i am having is, when i call this function the key is deleted form the object, but react does not update the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the problem i am having is, when i call this function the key is deleted form the object, but react does not update the state.

That is because you should not mutate state. Using `delete description[key]` will mutate the state, and doesn't inform React that a re-render should be triggered.

You should use `setDescription` to inform React about a state change. And instead of mutating the existing state, create a new one without the `key` property. This can easily be done with [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#computed_object_property_names_and_destructuring).

```js
const remove = (key) => {
  setDescription(({ [key]: value, ...description }) => description);
};
```

In the solution above we extract the value of the `key` property and store it in the `value` variable. All other properties (without `key`) are collected in a new object and stored in the `description` variable.

This process essentially creates a copy of the old description without the `key` property and uses it as the new state.

---

If you pass `remove` as a property to other components you could consider using [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) as well. This stabilises the identity of the `remove` function and could result in less re-renders.

```js
const remove = useCallback((key) => {
  setDescription(({ [key]: value, ...description }) => description);
}, []);
```

Normally you pass your dependencies in the dependency array at the end, but because [the identity of `setDescription` is stable](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) you can omit this dependency.

If all the dependencies have a stable identity or the dependency array is empty, the resulting function has a stable identity as well.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you're mutating a local instance of your state. You should update the state through the `useState` hook.

```
const remove = (key) => {
   setDescription(description => ({
     ...description,
     [key]: undefined
   }))
}
```

Note that you should never mutate your state! This can cause bugs in your application. So in the code above, we make a new object, copy the data we have, and then just set `[key]` to undefined, effectively deleting the value there.

Comment: changing the key to undefined made the component crash, but     setDescription(description => ({
     ...description
   }))                                                                                                                                                       solved the issue.